# Custom android launcher isn't immediately responsive to touch events

Tags: android, android-launcher

I'm building a custom Android launcher; at the moment it's pretty simple, it's a SurfaceView that renders a set of icons, and the app registers itself as a custom launcher using the manifest.

The SurfaceView is a custom class and it listens for touch events by overriding `onTouchEvent`. As I've tested my launcher, I noticed that if I quickly go to the launcher from an app ("press home", except its a gesture these days) and then press a button on the launcher, the touch event (I'd expect ACTION_DOWN) doesn't register. There's basically a tiny bit of latency before ACTION_DOWNs are properly propagated to the SurfaceView, after launching the launcher. I'd guess the latency is between 500ms to 1 second.

Does anyone know why this might be or how I could debug this further? It's a small thing, but it makes it annoying when trying to quickly change apps.

Comment: Have you run an experiment to see if the problem is specific to `SurfaceView`?

Comment: That's a great idea. Yes I did try it with a regular view. I didn't subclass, I just added a touch listener. The problem did reproduce. Thanks for the comment!